# How to dynamically generate Joi schema and save it to state as object in React JS

Tags: reactjs, joi

I have method dynamically generates edit form for objects but i have got an error "AssertionError: Invalid schema content:" when i am trying to use this schema to validate my object. Here is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import Joi from "joi-browser";

class CrudEdit extends Form {

state = {
    columns: [{ path: "id", label: "ID", tableColumn: true, editable: false },
      {
        path: "name",
        label: "Name",
        tableColumn: true,
        editable: true,
        type: "text"
      },
      {
        path: "email",
        label: "Email",
        tableColumn: true,
        editable: true,
        type: "email"
      },
      {
        path: "phone",
        label: "Phone",
        tableColumn: true,
        editable: true,
        type: "text"
      }]
}

schema = {
    name: Joi.string().label("Name"),
    email: Joi.string().label("Email"),
    phone: Joi.string().label("Phone")
};

async componentDidMount() {
    const { data: object } = await http.get(component + "/" + id);
    const schema = this.renderSchema();
    this.setState({ data: object.data, schema: schema });
}

renderSchema = () => {
    const { columns } = this.state;
    const schema = {};
    columns
      .filter(column => column.editable === true)
      .map(column => (schema[column.path] = Joi.string().label(column.label)));
    return schema;
  };
}
```

So after that i am trying to validate object using this schema generated in this method:

```
validate = () => {
    const options = {
      abortEarly: false
    };
    const { error } = Joi.validate(this.state.data, this.state.schema, options);
    if (!error) return null;
    const errors = {};
    error.details.map(item => (errors[item.path[0]] = item.message));
    return errors;
  };
```

when i change Joi.validate(this.state.data, this.state.schema, options); to Joi.validate(this.state.data, this.schema, options); Generated from state schema to saved in variable, everything works fine.

```
    "joi-browser": "^13.4.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6"
```

Comment: There's a few problems here. First off, it should only be `state = ...` not `this.state = ...`. Secondly, I matched the brackets and saw that it should be `this.schema` instead of `this.state.schema`

Comment: Please post your image as text. See [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged) for details.

Comment: @BrianLe this is because it is not full code, just parts of it i dont want to post all code because i dont have any problem with it )) Ok, thank you, i have changed .this state to state, in real code there is constructor thats why this there

Comment: @BrianLe Schema should be saved to the state or variable it doesnt matter, now renderSchema makes an object and saves it to state, so Joi for validation takes this schema from state, validate method in another component Form, this component just inherit the state ,extends Form